# NDSolve: input a value for a parameter from a list of values

Tags: differential-equations, parameters

I have a parameter in an equation which has a different value at each step from a list of values calculated in a former NDSolve differential equation.  While what I am trying to achieve is more complicated, I am working with a simple test trying to get this to work.  So I first make a list of the values that the parameter will be from one unrelated system  Then I take those and I need NDSolve to use each value from the list at each time step in the new system.  Can someone please help?  I have included the simpler test code that I have been working on. I want the parameter a to be the ith value in the list.

```
ClearAll[a]
{xf, yf} = {x, y} /. 
   First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, 
      y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 6}, 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, 
     StartingStepSize -> 1/2];
xl = MapThread[Append, {xf["Grid"], xf["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
alist = Table[xf["ValuesOnGrid"], {i, 1}];
alist = Flatten[alist]
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, {y}, {t, 0, 
   6}, {a}, Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 1/2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sol` in the form `(y[a][t] /. sol)`, e.g., plotting with several values from `alist`

```
Plot[Evaluate[(y[#][t] /. sol) & /@ alist[[5 ;; 25 ;; 5]]], {t, 0, 6},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For all values of `alist`

```
plt = Plot[Evaluate[(y[#][t] /. sol) & /@ alist], {t, 0, 6}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 210}}]
```

[image]

For `a` varying continuously

```
{mina, maxa} = MinMax[alist]

(* {-0.99992, 1.} *)

ParametricPlot[{t, (y[a][t] /. sol)},
 {t, 0, 6}, {a, mina, maxa},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 210}},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

To look at each value separately,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[(y[#][t] /. sol) &[alist[[i]]]], {t, 0, 6}, 
  PlotLabel -> StringForm["a = ``", alist[[i]]]],
 {{i, 100}, 1, Length[alist], 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Note that the `Manipulate` allows the `PlotRange` to adaptively change. In the earlier plots, the curves with negative slopes are lost in the scale of the curves with large values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I don't think this is what I can use.  I need NDSolve to evaluate each timestep with a new value of alist, not a different plot for each constant value of a, or am I misunderstanding your solution?

Comment: @Anne - The `NDSolve` is not dependent on `a`; only the `ParametricNDSolve` is. You can evaluate `(y[a][t] /. sol)` with an element from `alist` and any value of `t` in the interval `{0, 6}`.

Comment: What I want, is for the equation to be solved at each timestep with the corresponding ith alist value.  This doesn't work but something like this. 
```
Plot[Evaluate[(y[#][t] /. sol) & /@ alist[[i]]], {t, 0, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: @Anne this is precisely what Bob has shown, in multiple different ways. If your `alist` is flat, as I see it is, you would do something like what you have written, except without the `[[i]]` part to it, as Bob shows for “all values of `alist`”.